# CouchDB $in query results in Error : 400 Client Error: Bad Request bad_arg Bad argument for operator $in:

Tags: python-2.7, couchdb, cloudant, python-cloudant

While executing a CouchDB query with the $in option , it results in error.

> 400 Client Error: Bad Request bad_arg Bad argument for operator $in: <<91,,,107,34,93>>

The query being used is

```
{u'$and': [{u'messageContent.component': {u'$in': 
u'["AccountMock","AccountMock"]'}}, {u'messageContent.teamId': {u'$in': 
u'["mockteam-3-1","123"]'}}, {u'messageContent.userId': {u'$in': 
u'["mockuser-3-1","mockuser-2-1"]'}}, {u'messageContent.messageType': 
{u'$in': u'["Creating Mock Account","Creating"]'}}, 
{u'messageContent.subcomponent': {u'$in': 
u'["CreateAccountMock","Create Account"]'}}]}
```

Please suggest ways to get over this.

Comment: Have you tried to use curl for testing? just to discard a python JSON composition issue. This looks strange u'["Creating Mock Account","Creating"]', it should be an array not an unicode string

Comment: Yes, did try the curl too. but no luck.

Comment: The above  unicode string is being converted to the following 
on doing json.dumps() 
{"$and": 
  [
    {"messageContent.component": {"$in": ["AccountMock","AccountMock"] }}, 
    {"messageContent.teamId": {"$in": ["mockteam-3-1","123"]  }}, 
    {"messageContent.userId": {"$in": ["mockuser-3-1",'mockuser-2-1"] }}, 
    {"messageContent.messageType": {"$in": ["Creating Mock Account","Creating"] }}, 
    {"messageContent.subcomponent": {"$in": ["CreateAccountMock","Create Account"] }
    }
   ]
  }

Comment: Here ["mockuser-3-1",'mockuser-2-1"] there is a ', it is correct?